# two ways binding between grandchild and parent component

Tags: angular

I am trying to reflect the model value through 3 layers ( parent ->child -> grand Child) but i couldn't..
I created a textbox component .
and a addressInfo component which uses the textBox component. I added a two ways binding property. [(address)] to the addressInfo component to hold the model value.
and created bankDetails component which uses addressInfo component. now when i add [(address)] to the value of the model doesnt get reflected to its model . even though i can see that [(address)} on addressInfo component and ngModel at textBox component hold the correct value

Can you please help?

note: actualy my problem is kinda opposite to the issue  #7645 on github

```
my code:
textBox.ui.html:
<input #hTextBox
      [(ngModel)]="value"
    />
textBox.ui.ts:

private _value: string;
@Input()  get value(): string {
return this._value;
}
set value(val) {
if (this._value === val) return;
this._value = val;
this.valueChange.emit(val);

if (val.length == 0)
  this.showViewPassword = false;
else
  this.showViewPassword = true;
}


@Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter();

addressInfo.component.html: 

<h-textBox [disabled]="disabled" [(value)]="poBoxNum" [required]="required"> 
 </h-textBox>

addressInfo.component.ts:

//private _poBoxNum: string;
//@Input() get poBoxNum(): string {
//  debugger;
//  return this._poBoxNum;
//}
//set poBoxNum(val) {
//  debugger;
//  if (this._poBoxNum === val) return;
//  this._poBoxNum = val;
//  this.valueChange.emit(val);
//}

//@Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter();

bankDetails.component.html:

 <address-info [disabled]="disabled"
                     [(poBoxNum)]="poBoxNum">                  
        </address-info>

bankDetails.component.ts:
poBoxNum: string= "555" ;
```

Comment: Could you provide a code example of what you've tried so far?

Comment: Yes but could you post your actual code?

Comment: @Zalshabab Post your code in the question instead. It's unreadable in comments ;) Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: sorry I am new to posting to the forum.. I edited my question with my code.

Comment: I posted the code on the question area.. can you please have a look?@https://stackoverflow.com/users/2912011/david-rogers.  Thanks a lot :)